# How do I extend the ViewPort and use it to paint a "window" of 3D graphics on the screen

Tags: libgdx

I need to create a 3D perspective camera viewport of 480x480 and display it on the bottom right corner of the screen.  The rest of the screen is filled with 2D  graphics.

I tried extending Viewport and using viewportX, and viewportY as well as viewportHeight and viewportWidth, but the test 3D object does not draw.

I followed this tutorial to get the basic prototype going.
https://code.google.com/p/libgdx-users/wiki/Decals

How do I properly extend the ViewPort and use it to paint a "window" of 3D graphics on the screen ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following could be used to have a `Viewport` with a fixed size of 480x480 which is placed on the bottom left corner. If you supply a `PerspectiveCamera` to it, everything will be rendered in this area.

```
public class CustomViewport extends Viewport {

    public CustomViewport (Camera camera) {
        this.camera = camera;
    }

    @Override
    public void update (int screenWidth, int screenHeight, boolean centerCamera) {
        viewportX = 0;
        viewportY = 0;
        viewportWidth = 480;
        viewportHeight = 480;
        worldWidth = 480;
        worldHeight = 480;
        super.update(screenWidth, screenHeight, false);
    }

}
```

If you want to render somewhere else after that, you have to "reset" the `glViewport()` via `Gdx.gl.glViewport(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());`

Now you are free to render whereever you want, for example in the top and right areas which were left blank.

[This test](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/ViewportTest2.java) shows another example of how to render in those areas.